# define dplyr objects in shiny without reactive

Tags: dplyr, shiny

Is there a way to create an interim dplyr object in server section of a shiny app that is filtered by an input$var argument from the ui section that is **not** wrapped in reactive() so that after it is filtered it is used in further "downstream" analysis?

I know if I wrap the the data object in reactive() it will work, I'm trying to see if there is a way to do it without it.

Alternatively if did wrap reactive() around the data object, is there a way to do additional dplyr function on it (eg as if it was a dplyr object?)

example below

```
library(shiny)

library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::selectInput("var",label = "Input",choices = names(diamonds))
  ,shiny::plotOutput("plot")
  
  )
  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

    
 data <-  diamonds |> 
    ggplot(aes(y=price,x=.data[[input$var]]))+
        geom_point()

 output$plot <-   renderPlot(data)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- if you wrap the data argument in reactive() then you can continue to use ggplot functions or if it was a dplyr object you can continue to use dplyr functions

eg.

```
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::selectInput("var",label = "Input",choices = names(diamonds))
  ,shiny::plotOutput("plot")
  
  )
  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  #wrap in reactive()
 data <-  
reactive(
{
diamonds |> 
    ggplot(aes(y=price,x=.data[[input$var]]))+
        geom_point()
}
)

 output$plot <-   renderPlot(
data()+
#can add additional ggplot functions 
theme_classic())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```